# What is known about the equation $p^i + q^j = 2^k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

The equation $p^i + q^j = 2^k$, with $p,q$ odd primes and $i,j > 2$, seems to have no solutions. Does this result/conjecture have a name?

What is the intuition behind $p + q = 2^k$ having plenty of solutions (special case of Goldbach's conjecture) while the equation above probably has none?

Comment: It should follow from a sufficiently strong form of the abc conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture

Comment: A more general conjecture, which would also follow from a sufficiently strong form of the abc conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture

Comment: The intuition is that sums of two high powers are few and far between, and powers of two are even scarcer, so you wouldn't expect to find many solutions.